# Elasticsearch: Different result when query has escaped character

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2

How does Elasticsearch manage escaped characters in query?

I have a document where sku field is set as keyword.

```
{
    "_index": "magento2_product_1_v45",
    "_type": "document",
    "_source": {     
        "sku": "414-123
    }
}
```

The search API below gives the document result: **sku:414-123**

```
http://localhost:9200/magento2_product_1_v45/_search?q=sku:414-123
{
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "magento2_product_1_v45",
            "_type": "document",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.2876821,
            "_source": {
                "store_id": "1",
                "sku": "414-123"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

But the following does not retrieve the document: **sku:414\-123**

```
http://localhost:9200/magento2_product_1_v45/_search?q=sku:414\\-123
{
"hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
}
```

}

Magento is be default escaping the dash. Elasticsearch seems to be treating the escape character as part of the query string.

Comment: please add your schema mappings

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters)

You need to append special character in query string with '\'. In your case the your application is sending this two times which i am afraid treats or expects second '\' as part of string.

You need to modify your query as follows.

`http://localhost:9200/magento2_product_1_v45/_search?q=sku:414\-123`

Comment: This makes sense, but why does it not retrieve the document when using below API request (Magento sent this request to ES)

`POST http://localhost:9200/magento2_product_1_v45/_search?pretty`

`{
 "query": {
  "should": [
   {
    "match": {
     "sku": {
      "query": "414\\-123",
      "operator": "OR"
     }
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}`

Magento escapes the dash, JSON escapes the escape character hence the double escape. But ES should be able to read the query as "414\-123"

Comment: i don't think ES will be read query as "414\-123" when params passed is "414\\-123". They have very specifically mentioned on single "\" to use

Answer (score 0):

When performing queries in Elasticsearch, the analyzer that is being applied under the hood should be taken into account (by default Standard analyzer). If you specify the value "414-123" in the query term, Elasticsearch will split this value in two different tokens "414" and "123" and will retrieve any document having present one of these 2 terms applying an OR operation. It is also important to check the type of the "sku" field, there is a big difference between the types "text" and "keyword". As you need to search for "414-123" (all together) the type of this field must be keyword, otherwise Elasticsearch will tokenize it.

Comment: Yes, the sku is of type keyword. My current problem is why Elasticsearch is not retrieving the document when the dash in escaped as below.

` { "sku": { "query": "414\\-123", "operator": "OR" } }`
 > No result.
` { "sku": { "query": "414-123", "operator": "OR" } }`
 > With result

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before with literal searches where dashes need to be considered, and switched the query type to match_phrase and set the field to [field].keyword, example;

```
$params           = [];
$params['index']  = 'the_index';
$params['type']   = 'product';
$field            = 'sku.keyword';
$selected         = '414-123';

$params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = ['match_phrase' => [$field => "$selected"]];

$client = $this->clientBuilder;
$response = $client->search($params);
```